# Allowing user to change the font size within an application

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, font-size

Is there any way to allow the user to change the size of text throughout an application? I want the user to be able to select the option from a drop down menu in the `ActionBar` and change the size of the text throughout the application.

Comment: did you get some help in this?